# useForm data is not showing in the console

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am developing gmail-clone, I am using useForm for validating data. When I enter data in the form and print it to the console, nothing happens

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    };
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input name='to' placeholder='To' type='text' {...register('to', { required: true })} />
            <input name='subject' placeholder='Subject' type='text' {...register('subject', { required: true })} />
            <input name='message' placeholder='Type your message here...' type='text' className='sendMail_message' {...register('message', { required: true })} />

            <div className='sendMail_options'>
                <Button className='sendMail_send'>Send</Button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass type='submit' prop in the button component.

```
<Button type='submit' className='sendMail_send'>Send</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getFormData(formId){
        let keyValueList = [];
        let form = document.getElementById(formId)// get the form somehow
        for ( let i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
            let e = form.elements[i];
            if(e.name!=='') {
                keyValueList[encodeURIComponent(e.name)] = encodeURIComponent(e.value);
            }
        }
        return keyValueList;
    }
    const onSubmit = () => {
        let data = getFormData('formId');
        console.log(data)
        //todo: validate data
        return false;
    };
</script>

<form onsubmit="return onSubmit()" id="formId" >...</form>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: Haizz! OK @NathanOliver. As a programmer I think nothing is clearer than a single line of sample code.
I think she and others will understand the problem here and based on that get a better solution for themselves.
Besides, I'm not very good at explaining.